# Projection Valued Measure acting on approximate eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis

The spectral theorem say that we can always construct a projection valued measure (PVM) associated with an self-adjoint operator. I believe the PVM sends the eigenvalue of the operator to the projection that projects onto the eigenvectors of that eigenvalue, but I'm not so sure (although I strongly believe so due to the fact that $A=\int_R \lambda P(d\lambda)$). I want confirmation on this or proof that this isn't true. However, the more disturbing thing to me is that I have absolutely no idea what the PVM does to the approximate eigenvalues - of course except by letting the PVM act on it. I'm trying to understand this topic in the context of how it relates to the change of a state, $\psi$, in physics after measurement, which is given by $P(E) \psi P(E) \div Tr(numerator) $, where E is the value of the measurement and P is the PVM associated with the observable. I plan to read books on functional analysis later, which I think should contain my answers or at least develop the machinery for me to figure it out by myself, but I absolutely don't have the time right now so I would like to work with what I have and get an answer. Thanks.

Comment: The spectral theorem gives you a family of projections $P(\lambda)$ so that $\int_{\Bbb R}\lambda dP(\lambda)$ converges pointwise to the operator. The integral here is the Riemann Stieltjes integral. In the case that $A$ is compact it is diagonalisable and $P(\lambda)$ is the projection onto the eigenspaces with eigenvalues $≤\lambda$. In the continuous spectrum case you have here a generalisation of this idea, $P(\lambda)$ is the projection onto all modes of the operator $≤\lambda$ (eg in the case of the operator $x$ on $L^2$ it corresponds to multiplication with $\chi_{(-\infty,x]}$).

Comment: I don't really see how P($\lambda$) would be the projection onto the eigenspaces with eigenvalues $≤\lambda$ though. Wouldn't we overcount?

Comment: I think I get it now. Does P($\lambda$) actually means P(${(-\infty, \lambda ]}$)?